EF Core dependency injection
I'm new to DI and I ran into a problem. I'm making an Avalonia app in C# which uses a local PostgreSQL database. When registering in the app, it will concurrently check if the email and username already exist in the database, and therefore showing the according error.
private async Task registerCommand()
{
     var service = this.user_service;
     Task<bool> exists_username = service.ExistsByUsernameAsync(this.UsernameField.Text);
     Task<bool> exists_email = service.ExistsByEmailAdressAsync(this.EmailField.Text);
     var results = await Task.WhenAll(exists_username , exists_email);

     // ....
}        

I get these errors:

InvalidOperationException: A second operation was started on this context instance before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads concurrently using the same instance of DbContext. For more information on how to avoid threading issues with DbContext

and

ReactiveUI.UnhandledErrorException: 'An object implementing IHandleObservableErrors (often a ReactiveCommand or ObservableAsPropertyHelper) has errored, thereby breaking its observable pipeline. To prevent this, ensure the pipeline does not error, or Subscribe to the ThrownExceptions property of the object in question to handle the erroneous case.

Concurrently using the same instance of DbContext? I'm registering it as a scoped service.
public static void AddCommonServices(this IServiceCollection collection)
{
      collection.AddScoped<UserService>();
      collection.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
      collection.AddScoped<DatabaseContext>();
}

User repository:
public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
     private DatabaseContext context = null!;

     public UserRepository(DatabaseContext dbcontext) => this.context = dbcontext; 
     // ....
}        

User Service :
public class UserService
{
      private IUserRepository repository;

      public UserService(IUserRepository userRepository) => this.repository = userRepository;
     // ....
}        

Where it all begins:
private void goToRegister() => this.authVM.AuthContent = new RegisterVM(authVM, services.GetRequiredService<UserService>());

Help please?
I should add that when doing the 2 tasks one by one, they work just fine, so my question is that the same DbContext is called from different threads?

You’re running two queries at the same time in your code. Don’t do that and the problem will go away. Just run them normally one after another.

Side note: use collection.AddDbContext, i.e. the EF-provided method to register the context as scoped.

You didn't mention what kind of app your building. Is it web application? If so, multi-threading is usually not a good idea in web applications. Also, I doubt if multi-threaded query will yield any performance benefits.
EF DbContext is just not designed for multi-threading, so you should try using a different approach.
For example, you can check if user exists both by email address and username in one query. The key is to check if there is a user with given email OR with given username.
private async Task<bool> ExistsAsync(string email, string username)
{
    return await _dbContext
        .Users
        .AnyAsync(user => user.Email == email || user.Username == username);
}


It's a windows appllication

"This is safe from concurrent access issues in most ASP.NET Core applications because there is only one thread executing each client request at a given time, and because each request gets a separate dependency injection scope (and therefore a separate DbContext instance)." - from Microsoft docs. It is possible to multi-thread, the problem is I'm using the same context at the same time for my tasks. A new context should be created for each one.

@solodeving OK. But for this one, I really don't think you need multi-threading. Did you try the query that I suggested? You can check if the user exists both by email or username in one query. That should be more efficient.

I know I can work around it, and yeah my app is small it won't cost any performance, but I just want to learn new things! Thanks though.

the issue with your code is that you're not using the async/await correctly,
the DatabaseContext instance is not thread-safe reference.
here you can understand more about DbContext.
you cannot use the Task.WhenAll on multi-database operations.
here's an example code of what you have to do:
private async Task registerCommand()
{
     var service = this.user_service;
     var exists_username = await service.ExistsByUsernameAsync(this.UsernameField.Text);
     Task<bool> exists_email = await service.ExistsByEmailAdressAsync(this.EmailField.Text);
     // rest of logic
}        


I wanted to use task.WhenAll() just for executing the tasks concurrently. The problem is that I'm using the same dbcontext in both tasks.

@solodeving you can not do such a thing in EFCore you need to separate the DB Calls
